# Find minimum distance between digits from 0-9

Tags: excel

How to write formula in excel, to findout minimum distance between digits from 0-9, the minimum distance will be between 0-5 only. 
digits will be entered in column wise vertically, say entered in column A,and Column B ,Resulting minimum distance of A1 And B1 should be entered in column C1 like wise Some examples below

```
column A
4
4
8
6
2
3
9
3
9
1
column B
9
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
Resulting column C should be like below
5
4
3
4
1
1
4
3
2
3
```

if same digit in both the column then the resulting column will be zero, there should not be a digit between 6-9 in resulting column .please help , how to write formula in excel

Answer (score 0):

Based on your expected results for Column C, you want to test the 1's place value by itself and also with an assumed 10's place value of +1 within a Base 10 number.  With your test values in A1:A10 and B1:B10, enter the following formula in C1:
    =MIN(MAX(A1:B1)-MIN(A1:B1),(MIN(A1:B1)+10)-MAX(A1:B1))

Comment: i entered the suggested formula but it is showing the formula itself in c1, it is not showing the result in c1